# 128Gb SD Card not detected

Tags: sd-card

I just bought a SDXC 128Go card. I've put it in my internal card reader and it's not recognized by Ubuntu.

I already have another SD Card (SDHC 32 Go) and it's working fine on ubuntu.

I have a dual boot with Windows and I can use the 128Gb card on windows. I tried formating it with NTFS or exFat but it doesn't change anything.

My Ubuntu version is 18.04.2 LTS. I also installed `exfat-fuse` and `exfat-utils` but it doesn't help.

I start to think it's a driver issue because I can't even try to mount manually: there is no `/dev/mmcXXX` when the 128gb card is connected. When the 32Gb one is, I can see it's auto mounted from `/dev/mmcblk0`.

I have a Lenovo Ideapad Yoga 13 laptop, and my card reader is (from lsusb) "Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller"

Comment: Maybe related: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/487968/detection-of-certain-sandisk-sd-cards-fails-with-realtek-rts522a-reader